# Duplicate function produces a large factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame with one column like this:

```
col1
line1
line1
line2
```

I try to remove duplicate using this:

```
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

but it produces a large factor instead of removing the duplicate. The result of structure something like is this:

```
str(df2)
 Factor w/ 7472 levels
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We ask that for questions involving troubleshooting code that you provide a reproducible example. You can use `dput()` to share the data.

Answer (score 2):

When you have just one column, you need to use `drop = FALSE` to get a dataframe back:

```
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df), , drop = FALSE]
```

another option is using the `unique` function:

```
df2 <- unique(df)
```

the result of both approaches is the same:

```
> df2
   col1
1 line1
3 line2
```

Comment: You don't need drop except when there's only 1 column (and if there's only 1 column why would you want a data.frame?).

Comment: `drop = FALSE` is indeed only needed when you have one column in your dataframe (which is the case as OP described)

Answer (score 0):

```
col1 <- c("line1",
          "line1",
          "line2")

df <- data.frame(col1=col1, x=c(1,2,3))

df1 <- df[!duplicated(df$col1),]
df1
```

> ```
>    col1 x
> 1 line1 1
> 3 line2 3
> ```

```
class(df1)
```

> [1] "data.frame"

Comment: This doesn't return a dataframe, which is what OP wants to my understanding

Comment: @h3rm4n It returns a data.frame when there's more than 1 column. If there's 1 column you shouldn't use a data.frame.

Comment: yes, but OP only has one column

Comment: you changed the example data, which isn't correct imo